# Clear the cell of column B if cell A is empty - RANGE

Tags: excel, vba

Got a problem and looking for some advice. I've been using the below code for a while now in Excel, it clears the contents of column B if cell A is empty. It works great, but I now need it to work for a specific range (A6:B35). Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Column = 1 Then
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
End If
End If

exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test if the active cell (target) falls in the range A6:A35. Like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If not intersect(target, range("A6:A35")) is nothing then
   If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
      Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End if
exitHandler:

End Sub
```

You should also indent your code so it is more readable. It will help with loops and IF statements.

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer is perfect.

Comment: @Andy_NPTdidnt you say you wanted to look at A1:B35? (Hi Ingeborg).

Comment: @brettdj, I read it as "monitor column A from row 3 to 35 and change column B"

Comment: Good point, i think you are right.  The target.column part is redundant though as the intersect test has already looked at where the changes range is column a

Comment: Right. I didn't really look at the details of the code. :P I'll amend.

Comment: Always safer to work with the intersect range rather than Target - if only part of Target is inside the intended area (i.e. When multi-cell update occurs) you still end up working on the whole range...

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("A6:B35"))

If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng2 In rng1
    If rng2.Validation.Type = 3 Then rng2.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```